# Linq to XML Query not picking anything

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a rather complex XML document

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="-------">
  <OperationRequest>
    <HTTPHeaders>
    </HTTPHeaders>
    <RequestId>0S57WGDPNC7T8HNBV76K</RequestId>
    <Arguments>
    </Arguments>
    <RequestProcessingTime>0.441776990890503</RequestProcessingTime>
  </OperationRequest>
  <Items>
    <Request>
      <ItemSearchRequest>
      </ItemSearchRequest>
    </Request>
    <TotalResults>1020</TotalResults>
    <TotalPages>102</TotalPages>
    <Item>
      <ASIN>B004WL0L9S</ASIN>
      <SalesRank>1</SalesRank>
      <ItemAttributes>
         <Manufacturer>Georgia Pacific Consumer Products LP (Cut-Sheet Paper)</Manufacturer>
         <Title>GP Copy &amp; Print Paper, 8.5 x 11 Inches Letter Size, 92 Bright White, 20    Lb, Ream of 500 Sheets (998067R)</Title>
      <ItemAttributes>
    </Item>
  <Items>
```

I run this query over it and it returns of list of zero:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
List<Item> Items = (from c in doc.Elements("Item")
          select new Item
          {
            Title = c.Element("Title").Value
            SaleRank = c.Element("SaleRank").Value
            ASIN = c.Element("ASIN").Value
           }).ToList<Item>();
```

I am really new to XLinq but according to the documentation that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to add the namespace to query.

```
XNamespace ns = NAMESPACE;

var items = (from c in doc.Descendants(ns +"Item")
    select new Item
    {
       Title = c.Element(ns + "ItemAttributes").Element(ns + "Title").Value,
       SalesRank = c.Element(ns +"SalesRank").Value,
       ASIN = c.Element(ns + "ASIN").Value
    }).ToList<Item>();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have not valid xml. Here is example how it should looks:

```
<ItemSearchResponse >
    <OperationRequest>
        <HTTPHeaders> </HTTPHeaders>
        <RequestId>0S57WGDPNC7T8HNBV76K</RequestId>
        <Arguments> </Arguments>
        <RequestProcessingTime>0.441776990890503</RequestProcessingTime>
    </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
        <Request>
            <ItemSearchRequest> </ItemSearchRequest>
        </Request>
        <TotalResults>1020</TotalResults>
        <TotalPages>102</TotalPages>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>B004WL0L9S</ASIN>
            <SalesRank>1</SalesRank>
            <ItemAttributes>
                <Manufacturer>Georgia Pacific Consumer Products LP (Cut-Sheet Paper)</Manufacturer>
                <Title>GP Copy &amp; Print Paper, 8.5 x 11 Inches Letter Size, 92 Bright White, 20 Lb, Ream of 500 Sheets (998067R)</Title>
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

And this code works with it:

```
var Items = (from c in doc.Root.Element("Items").Elements("Item")
                  select new Item()
                  {
                    Title = c.Element("ItemAttributes").Element("Title").Value,
                    SaleRank = c.Element("SalesRank").Value,
                    ASIN = c.Element("ASIN").Value
                   }).ToList();
```

or with `Descendants`:

```
var Items = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("Item")
                  select new
                  {
                    Title = c.Element("ItemAttributes").Element("Title").Value,
                    SaleRank = c.Element("SalesRank").Value,
                    ASIN = c.Element("ASIN").Value
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I trying to use it against the webresponse I am getting returned to me. Other than missing that closing tag, that is copy and pasted version of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your use of `.Elements(XName)` which it seems you're assuming is recursive. It is not, It only inspects direct children of the target (in this case the document).

I believe the function you're looking for is `.Descendants(XName)` which will look recursively, but be warned this is not very fast on massive XML docs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the difference between Elements and Descendants

```
  var items = (from c in doc.Descendants("Item")
               select new Item
               {
                 Title = c.Element("ItemAttributes").Element("Title").Value,
                 SaleRank = c.Element("SalesRank").Value,
                 ASIN = c.Element("ASIN").Value
               }).ToList<Item>();
```

Elements a list of Xml Elements directly underneath the current Element (i.e. only 1 level deep).  Descendants will retrieve all elements.

Based on your Xml and your query, I showed the use of Descendant and Element.  The initial loop uses Descendants(), but access to Title uses to chained Element() calls.

I tried running the code, and I'm assuming the xmlns was removed for posting, but your actual code has a real namespace in it.  If not, that maybe a problem you need to resolve first.